# How to reflect host permission in the container docker?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I know that it is impossible to change the permissions of a file shared via volume, because a matter of default, and from what I understand, the permissions of the docker container, reflect the permissions of the host, however, this is not happening in my case, the docker simply changes permissions on all files to 755, and some files must have specific permissions.

HOST:

[image]

Docker Container:

[image]

Docker File:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

#Updating operating system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade

##Installing essential packages
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils software-properties-common curl bash-completion vim git supervisor


## Add Scripts
ADD ./start.sh /start.sh
EXPOSE  80
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
#CMD ["/start.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT echo $XDEBUG_CONFIG >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini && service php7.3-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/usr/share/nginx/html
  - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/nginx/sites-enabled}:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
  - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/php.ini
  - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/nginx}:/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  Your Dockerfile contains a lot of PHP setup, for example, but nothing that specifically deals with file ownership or permissions.  I'm not clear what change you're trying to make or what behavior you're seeing or not.

Comment: Champion, that's exactly the point of the question, to make Docker respect my host's permission and not change everything to 755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption

> I know that it is impossible to change the permissions of a file shared via volume

Is only partially correct, there is actually a set of modes — `:ro` & `:rw` – you can use when mounting a volume via docker-compose that are described in the documentation:

> Standard modes are `ro` for read-only and `rw` for read-write (default).

*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3*

You can also use the `:Z` and `:z` modes if your host uses `selinux`.

> If you use `selinux` you can add the `z` or `Z` options to modify the selinux label of the **host file or directory** being mounted into the container. This affects the file or directory on the host machine itself and can have consequences outside of the scope of Docker.
>
> - The `z` option indicates that the bind mount content is shared among multiple containers.
> - The `Z` option indicates that the bind mount content is private and unshared.
>
> Use **extreme** caution with these options. Bind-mounting a system directory such as `/home` or `/usr` with the `Z` option renders your host machine inoperable and you may need to relabel the host machine files by hand.

*Source: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label*

Here is an example, on my host, here are the permissions of my files:

```
~ # ls -la ro rw 
ro:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 ben  staff   96 May 23 23:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 ben  staff  288 May 23 23:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 ben  staff    0 May 23 23:06 file

rw:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 ben  staff   96 May 23 23:06 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 ben  staff  288 May 23 23:16 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ben  staff    0 May 23 23:06 file
```

Then with this *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  test:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - ./ro:/root/ro:Z
      - ./rw:/root/rw:Z
    command: sleep 100000000000
```

Here is the result on the container

```
~ # ls -la ro rw
ro:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 May 23 21:06 .
drwx------    1 root     root          4096 May 23 21:17 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 May 23 21:06 file

rw:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            96 May 23 21:06 .
drwx------    1 root     root          4096 May 23 21:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 May 23 21:06 file
```